# How to Enqueue the Bootstrap Script and Style for WordPress Page Template but not Whole Site

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am new to WordPress and am building a single page template for my site. I want to keep my main WordPress theme for the majority of the site, but I have a very specific application that I want to use Bootstrap for on just a couple of pages. To avoid losing my custom work when the theme updates, I made a child theme with the page template and then selected that template from WordPress for the appropriate page.

I finally arrived at this script for my `functions.php` (based on example [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/174502/how-to-install-bootstrap-in-child-theme)):

```
<?php
function enqueue_child_theme_styles() {
//deregister the parent bootstrap style and script  
wp_deregister_style( 'bootstrap' );
wp_deregister_script( 'bootstrap' );

//enqueue my child theme stylesheet
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array('theme') );

//enqueue bootstrap in the child theme 
wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), NULL, true);
wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css', false, NULL, 'all');

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_child_theme_styles', PHP_INT_MAX);
```

That worked perfect for my page template, it now responds to Bootstrap classes... unfortunately, so does everything else on my site. How do I make this only apply if Wordpress is trying to load my page template, but ignore it in all other cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [is_page_template](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/200155/is-template-how-to-add-one-more-template)

```
if (is_page_template($templatename))
{
wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), NULL, true);

...etc

}
```

The link provided has an exact example you are looking for.

Comment: Basic question... what do I put for `'yourpagename'`? My template file is `course-manager.php`, but when I wrapped that whole script as you suggested and put `is_page('course-manager'))`, it broke the bootstrap script, and the rest of the site is still broken. Worst of both worlds...

Comment: Changed the answer,

Comment: Perfect, I've been working on that for days. Thank you!

Comment: That happens. Glad to have helped.